# Disk scheduling: Why use (C-)Scan instead of (C-)Look?

Tags: operating-systems

I don't get why SCAN is used when LOOK exists. Why move to the end, when there are no longer any pending requests in that direction?

- SCAN: In SCAN algorithm the disk arm moves into a particular direction and services the requests coming in its path and after reaching the end of disk, it reverses its direction and again services the request arriving in its path.
- LOOK: It is similar to the SCAN disk scheduling algorithm except for the difference that the disk arm in spite of going to the end of the disk goes only to the last request to be serviced in front of the head and then reverses its direction from there only.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disk-scheduling-algorithms/